# What is the Linear space $R^{2 \times 2}$ means visually in linear algebra?

Tags: linear-algebra

Why mathematicians decided to define a space of matrices if it does not make any sense visually?

What are the uses of such linear space?

and why my professor tells me that matrices can be written and are considered as vectors?

Comment: "Why mathematicians decided to define _____ if it does not make any sense visually?" - because _____ is something of interest to mathematicians. A better question is - why would a mathematical object need to make sense "visually" in order to be studied?

Comment: I agree with the comment above, mathematics are not only concerned with objects that make sense visually. But if you are looking for a visual interpretation of $2 \times 2$ matrices, you can look at rotation matrices, which are very visual. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix

Comment: Vector spaces have extremely nice properties as far as mathematical structures go.  If you recognize that a set is a vector space, you should definitely use that fact.

Comment: The question of "utility" is very subjective, an abstract mathematical theorem, such as Artin-Wedderburn for example, can be very useful for a mathematician that wants to classify mathematical objects. The question of utility is often used to imply economical or physical applicability.

Comment: What makes you think that $\Bbb R^{2 \times 2}$ doesn't make sense visually?  Do you think that the fact that we don't see in $4$ dimensions make $4$-dimensional spaces less important?

Comment: Here's a question for you: what, on a structural level, is the *difference* between a vector and a matrix?